# Raise custom Error

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to raise an error here but I'm new to Ruby so not sure what I'm doing wrong here

```
class ChangeError < StandardError; end
```

I changed this which was working:

```
return change.inject(0){|sum,x| sum + x } == amount ? change : raise ChangeError
```

to this

```
    return change.inject(0){|sum,x| sum + x } == amount ? change : raise ChangeError
```

And I get the error:

```
syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' (SyntaxError)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parentheses - `raise(ChangeError)`, they cannot be omitted in this case